# Is there a Salesforce equivalent to the LinkedIn "shareArticle" web thing?

Tags: salesforce, linkedin-api

The [LinkedIn social sharing feature](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) pops open a screen where you can set up an email (it knows all your LinkedIn contacts and stuff) and send a link to a page. I have been asked to create a feature like this that sends email from Salesforce. I've searched Salesforce's public docs and found no such feature. And I can't ask on their help forums without having a paid salesforce account (what's up with that?). So I'm hoping maybe someone can help me here!

Comment: You may get more answers on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com, but most likely this is something you'll need to custom build (depending on your exact requirements).

Comment: I didn't realize there was a special stack exchange for that. I'll go ask over there. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask an admin to move it for you. Posting the same question on multiple boards is discouraged

Comment: Turns out they are pretty useless and mean over there in that stack exchange. I like it here better :)